# Unknown script on all the page

Tags: javascript, joomla

I 've recently noticed that all my ajax calls fail on my website (a new blank page is loaded).
After analysis, I made the following observation:

The code below is added to all content-answer following a request to the server.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var style =document.createElement("style")
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(".adcefac { position:absolute;left:-74480px; }"));
  document.head.appendChild(style);
</script>

<script language="JavaScript">
  document.write("<img width='1' height='1' src='/?ad380782=1&amp;r="+escape(document.referrer)+"&amp;u="+escape(document.URL)+"&rnd="+Math.random()+"' />");
</script>
```

On every page of my website this code appears and I have absolutely no idea where it does come from...

Do you have any idea about the possible origin of such strange code?

Note: My website is based on a customized component for the CMS Joomla and it worked perfectly fine some weeks ago (I suppose the problem appears with an automatic update of Joomla).

Comment: can i know what extensions you have installed? any tracking plugin you have installed?

Comment: Even if I disable all the plugin from the admin side of the site, I still have this code at the end of the html page!!! An error message is displayed because some plugin are just required to display the website but after the content with the error message this script is still added. It drives me crazy.

Comment: The script produce the following request url for the image (1*1) : http://www.mywebsite.com/?ad380782=1&r=&u=http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php/fr/&rnd=0.5401749462042876. Do someone has an idea about the meaning with the parameters in the url : r, u and rnd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly it is malware. 
You can read about it on Sucuri's website. http://labs.sucuri.net/?details=counter.yadro.ru

You can use their malware site scanner as a good starting point.
https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/

If you are infected you need to.

1. Back up the site and database with a clean version

**or**

2. Obtain services from a place like https://myjoomla.com/ or https://sucuri.net/ to clean up and harden your website.

If you do not have a backup for the amount of headaches you can save,  I believe both services have a plans that are under $20 USD and is well worth it.

You may want to look into both if it comes to that.

This may not be the news you want to hear but believe me, many of us have been there more than once.

**Note**: I am not affiliated with sucuri or myjoomla